# using enumeration block

Tags: iphone

I have a issue with enumerationblock , when i try to access the vidoes and audios from the
phone using iPhone OS 4.0, i found the following api from the class AssetsLibrary

Invokes a given block passing as a parameter each of the asset groups that match the given asset group type.

```
- (void)enumerateGroupsWithTypes:(ALAssetsGroupType)types
                      usingBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock)enumerationBlock
                    failureBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)failureBlock
```

The signature for the ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock is given as follows :

```
typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock)(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop);
```

SO how can i create a ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock for passing as a parameter for the above method ..

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,
Mohammed Sadiq....

Comment: i think you are not allowed to publicly talk about upcoming iPhone OS Versions

Answer (score 0):

Blocks (closures) is a feature of C first introduced in [LLVM Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.txt), and actually made popular in Mac OS X 10.6, and ported to iPhoneOS on 4.0. Therefore you should be able to find a lot of non-NDA information about blocks, e.g. an introduction by Apple in http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH1-SW1.

Usually you declare the block as an anonymous function, like this:

```
 int x = 0;
 [foo … usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup* group, BOOL* stop) {
                       NSLog(@"%@", group);
                       ++ x;
                       if (x > 5)
                          *stop = YES;
                   } …];
```

Here the `^` introduces an inline block (anonymous function), and the rest is the definition of that function.

This function iterates over `foo`, prints the enumerated `group` to console, until the 5th item where the loop is broken.